# Java: Is there a way to retrieve, in a Set, an original object from its clone

Tags: java

I need to retrieve, in a Set, an original object from its clone.

I would like to do something like:

```
Set<Object> mySet;
public void myModifyMethod(Object clone){
    if(mySet.contains(clone)){
        Object original = mySet.get(clone); // get method does not seem to exist

        // Modify original object
    }
}
```

I could not find any method in the [Java SE 6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to do that. The only way I can think about is to iterate over the whole set but this is not efficient at all (I was hoping to achieve O(1) from the HashSet, not the O(n) from a sequential search).

Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Why not make it a `HashSet` if you need a `HashSet`?

Comment: Implement `hash` and `equals` so clones w/ the appropriate data will be equal.

Comment: @Dave This was actually done and the `mySet.contains(clone)` actually returns true. The issue is really that the get method does not exist in Set or HashSet (or I am blind and didn't find it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no get method on java sets**.

You could refactor and add all elements to hashmap - Map has the get method.

But why do you need *to retrieve, in a Set, an original object from its clone*, as you already have an instance of it, you are using that to check if it exists - just make sure you implement hashcode and equals appropriately.

Comment: I need to modify the "master instance" of the object for which I only have a clone. The Map would probably be a good solution. I had thought about it but wanted to see if there was another solution first.

Comment: Well, to start with, you shouldn't be modifying elements in a `Set` in the first place...Factor out the "identifying information" into an immutable key type, and the mutable parts into a value, and put them together in a `Map`.

Comment: @Louis I don't know why I didn't think about factoring the "identifying information". This is really cleaner and simpler. I actually found this notice in the Set API doc: "Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements"

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think of is using a `Map` where the original object is both the key and the value, and then doing something like `map.get(clone)` to obtain the original. Of course you should have `hash` and `equals` methods implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by implementing the Set interface using a Map. Here is my implementation :

```
public final class HandleSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

    private final HashMap<E, E> map;

    public HandleSet() {
        map = new HashMap<E, E>();
    }

    public E get(E o) {
        return map.get(o);
    }

    /* Implementation of Interface Set */

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return map.keySet().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o) {
        return map.put(o, o) == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return o.equals(map.remove(o));
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

}
```